# How to wrap jstree children with span so that i can group them

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

i wanted to wrap the whole `children` with `span`, so that i can give them background-color

i want wrap all children like below

```
  <span class="children-group-wrapper">
     <span>Group Child 1</span>
     <span>Group Child 2</span>
  </span>
```

**Css:**

```
span.children-group-wrapper{border:1px solid orange;}
```

**i'm creating** those 2 nodes `Group Child 1` and `Group Child 2` with below code:

```
$('#using_json_2').jstree().create_node('ajson2',  obj, "last");
```

**Below is my Desired Output(think border as a perfect border):**

[image]

**Note:** i don't want to use html jstree

```js
var treeData = [
  { "id" : "ajson1", "parent" : "#", "text" : "Simple root node"},
  { "id" : "ajson2", "parent" : "#", "text" : "Root node 2"}
];

var childrenGroup = [
  { "id" : "ajson3", "parent" : "ajson2", "text" : "Group Child 1",children:false,"icon":"fa fa-file-o",groupClass:'children-group-wrapper1'},
  { "id" : "ajson4", "parent" : "ajson2", "text" : "Group Child 2",children:false,"icon":"fa fa-file-o",groupClass:'children-group-wrapper1'},
   { "id" : "ajson5", "parent" : "ajson2", "text" : "2nd Group Child 1",children:false,"icon":"fa fa-file-o",groupClass:'children-group-wrapper2'},
    { "id" : "ajson6", "parent" : "ajson2", "text" : "2nd Group Child 2",children:false,"icon":"fa fa-file-o",groupClass:'children-group-wrapper2'}
];

var myTree = $('#using_json_2').jstree({ 'core' : {
   "check_callback": true,
   'data' : treeData // Use it here
}});

myTree.on('changed.jstree', function(e, data) {
   childrenGroup.forEach(function(obj){
      $('#using_json_2').jstree().create_node('ajson2',  obj, "last");
   });
    $('#using_json_2').jstree().open_node('ajson2');
});
```

```css
.children-group-wrapper1{
   border:1px solid orange;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.2.1/themes/default/style.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.2.1/jstree.min.js"></script>


<div id="using_json_2"> </div>
```

Please help me thanks in advance!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: You already have your desire output in snippet, what you want to do?

Comment: i want those 2 `children` to be  wrapped with `span` with `class="children-group-wrapper"` so that i can give entire `border` as shown in image

Comment: please pardon me for  `border` line in the image, consider it as a `border` for whole **wrapper**

Comment: You want to apply the class on load of jstree or you want apply it onclick?

Comment: The below **solution** doesn't solve my problem of **2 groups** separation,  please provide your solution.  Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: the only reason I am providing you a solution is because you are unable to add second group, please check my edited answer

Answer (score 2):

You already have an id of the tree now, you can just add class to it and get it working.

```
$("#ajson2").addClass("children-group-wrapper")
```

```js
var treeData = [{
    "id": "ajson1",
    "parent": "#",
    "text": "Simple root node",
    
  },
  {
    "id": "ajson2",
    "parent": "#",
    "text": "Root node 2",
    
  }
];

var childrenGroup = [{
    "id": "ajson3",
    "parent": "ajson2",
    "text": "Group Child 1",
    children: false,
    "icon": "fa fa-file-o"
  },
  {
    "id": "ajson4",
    "parent": "ajson2",
    "text": "Group Child 2",
    children: false,
    "icon": "fa fa-file-o"    
  }
];

var myTree = $('#using_json_2').jstree({
  'core': {
    "check_callback": true,
    'data': treeData // Use it here
  }
});

myTree.on('changed.jstree', function(e, data) {
  childrenGroup.forEach(function(obj) { 
    $('#using_json_2').jstree().create_node('ajson2', obj, "last");
  });
  $('#using_json_2').jstree().open_node('ajson2');
  $("#ajson2").addClass("children-group-wrapper")
});
```

```css
.children-group-wrapper {
  border: 1px solid orange;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.2.1/themes/default/style.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.2.1/jstree.min.js"></script>


<div id="using_json_2"></div>
```

if you want to apply the class to li you can use new supported property of the jstree

```
"li_attr": {
      "class": "children-group-wrapper"
    }
```

This will add the class attribute to li.

**EDIT:**

```js
var treeData = [{
    "id": "ajson1",
    "parent": "#",
    "text": "Simple root node"
  },
  {
    "id": "ajson2",
    "parent": "#",
    "text": "Root node 2"
  }
];

var childrenGroup = [{
    "id": "ajson3",
    "parent": "ajson2",
    "text": "Group Child 1",
    children: false,
    "icon": "fa fa-file-o",
    groupClass: 'children-group-wrapper1',
    "li_attr": {
      "class": "children-group-wrapperOpen"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": "ajson4",
    "parent": "ajson2",
    "text": "Group Child 2",
    children: false,
    "icon": "fa fa-file-o",
    groupClass: 'children-group-wrapper1',
    "li_attr": {
      "class": "children-group-wrapperClosed"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": "ajson5",
    "parent": "ajson2",
    "text": "2nd Group Child 1",
    children: false,
    "icon": "fa fa-file-o",
     "li_attr": {
      "class": "children-group-wrapper1Open"
    }
   
  },
  {
    "id": "ajson6",
    "parent": "ajson2",
    "text": "2nd Group Child 2",
    children: false,
    "icon": "fa fa-file-o",
     "li_attr": {
      "class": "children-group-wrapper1Closed"
    }
  }
];

var myTree = $('#using_json_2').jstree({
  'core': {
    "check_callback": true,
    'data': treeData // Use it here
  }
});

myTree.on('changed.jstree', function(e, data) {
  childrenGroup.forEach(function(obj) {
    $('#using_json_2').jstree().create_node('ajson2', obj, "last");
  });
  $('#using_json_2').jstree().open_node('ajson2');
});
```

```css
.children-group-wrapperOpen {
  border: 1px solid orange;
  border-bottom: 0px;
}

.children-group-wrapperClosed {
  border: 1px solid orange;
  border-top: 0px;
}

.children-group-wrapper1Open {
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-bottom: 0px;
}

.children-group-wrapper1Closed {
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.2.1/themes/default/style.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.2.1/jstree.min.js"></script>


<div id="using_json_2"></div>
```

Comment: I have accepted your question but, if i want 2 more items having separate group for them below  , `Group Child 1, Group Child 2`. how can i do it?

Comment: i have **Edited my Question**  Please see the **Output**

Comment: for `2nd Group Child 1,2nd Group Child 2` i want them in `red border`, **Dynamically**. please help me

Comment: @EaB what is your expectation on that?

Comment: i have group upload, so whichever is uploaded in a group i want to show them with different border i,e `orange  & red`. please help me to make `2nd Group Child 1  & 2nd Group Child 2` in **Red** `border` **Dynamically**

Comment: @EaB if you want to group them you can use li attribute style, check my edit

Comment: only `orange` (correct) **border** is appearing , i want `Red` **border** for 2nd group. can you please edit

Comment: @EaB you need to understand how I am applying the orange one and then apply the red border, you need to understand first and then only you can proceed further